# setOnClickListener is not recognised by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When we try to open a new activity with a button, setOnClickListener does not work. For some reason, Android Studio does not recognise it.

We are attempting to open a new activity when the button is pressed (but we haven't coded that bit yet).

[Our code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veioj.png)

We would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: You can't call that - or `findViewById()` - outside of a method. Move them to `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call. Also, please don't post only screenshots of code. Post all text as text.

Comment: Add it in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot simply call `next.setOnClickListener()` in the body of your `MainActivity` class; you must put that code inside a method (probably `onCreate()`).

Additionally, this line:

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
```

is technically OK but will never work (because you have not yet called `setContentView()` at this point in time).

Change your button declaration to simply

```
Button next;
```

and change your `onCreate()` to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```